# Topology of Normed Space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> $(X, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ is a normed space. Let $x \in X \setminus \{0\}$ and $Y \subset X$ is a subspace. Prove that if $Y$ is open then $Y=X$.

Which  technique  is  more  useful?  We  know that  if  a  set  is  open  then  complement  is  closed. Or  what  else,  directly  use  the  definition  of  open  set?

Comment: Use that $Y$ is a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Yes. Use the fact than open set contains an open ball around each point it contains. Then try to scale any other point of $X$ to fit inside that ball.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm probably forgetting something, but how do you know that $Y$ is a neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: We can show that any subspace of a topological vector space with non-empty interior must be the entire space. But what does $x$ have to do with your question?

Comment: @DanZimm: You know that $Y$ contains the origin because it is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: @Matt Doh! Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you have to say let $x\in X \{0\}$?

Comment: What Lost1 said but with $x \in X \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$Y$ is a (linear!) subspace, so $0 \in Y$. Then there is an open ball $B(0,r) \subset Y$, where $B(0,r) = \{ x: \|x\| < r \}$, because by assumption $Y$ is open so $0$ is an interior point of $Y$. If $x \neq 0$ is in $X$, then $y = \frac{r}{2 \|x\|}\cdot x$ has norm $\|y\| = \frac{r}{2\|x\|}\|x\| = \frac{r}{2} < r$, so $y \in Y$. As $Y$ is a linear subspace, $x = \frac{2\|x\|}{r} \cdot y$ is in $Y$ as well. So $Y = X$.